# How do I center an image in a div in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to horizontally center the 90% donut graph in the middle column div. I used class="center-block", but that doesn't seem to fix it. How do I get the image to center?

You can see the site here:
http://matthewtbrown.com/test/myprojects.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are floating the image to the left, just remove that. I assume you are only attempting to float the profile image with this code:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .middlecolumn img {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Since you already wrap your profile picture in a `div` with a specific class, you can change the above CSS to this:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .middlecolumn .personpic img {
        float: left;
    }
}
```